# Calculating the norm of an integral operator

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I have an operator $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $X = C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ with the supremum norm and $f$ is defined by

$$f(x) = \int_{-1}^{0} x(\tau)d\tau - \int_{0}^{1} x(\tau)d\tau, \quad\text{for all $x \in X$} $$

I have already proved that $f \in X^{*}$, but i'm struggling to determine $||f||$. My guess is that $||f|| = 2$ since i managed to prove that $||f|| \leq 2$ using integral properties and module triangular inequality. To get the opposite inequality i'm trying to find a continuous function $x$ with supremum norm equal to 1 such that $|f(x)| \geq 2$, but i've been unsuccessful. Maybe $||f||$ has another value but i'm not being able to see it. Any tips and help will be appreciated!

Comment: An example with$|f(x)|\ge2$ and $\|x\|=1$ does not exist, because of an easy upper bound calculation. Still, your answer $\|f\|=2$ is correct. Idea: Use functions equal to -1 on$[-1,-\epsilon]$ and equal to 1 on $[\epsilon,1]$.

Comment: @Benjamin thank you! I didn't realise the example really doesn't exist until you said. Thanks for the idea, it worked perfectly.